# How to centre substack in multiple summations?

Tags: formatting

This seems like it would be easy to do so pardon my inexperience but is it possible to centre a secondary line such that it is between both sums, whether using substack or by other means.

I currently have:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Please add the code of what you tried so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `stackengine` to achieve it, though the space before the `a_{ij}` must be manually inserted.  I show the standard expression (without the secondary subscript) to compare the spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^N a_{ij}
\]
\[
\stackunder[0pt]{\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^N}
  {\scriptstyle i\ne j\ne k}\,a_{ij}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a macro called `\doublesumwithlimits`, which takes up to 6 arguments, all of which may be empty. The first two arguments pertain to the first summation, the next two to the second summation, and the final two to the "outer" shell. No extra packages needed.

[image]

For obvious reasons, use this in display math mode only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\doublesumwithlimits[6]{%
   \mathop{\sum_{#1}^{#2}\,\sum_{#3}^{#4}}_{#5}^{#6}}
\begin{document}
\[
-\doublesumwithlimits{j=1}{N}{k=1}{N}{i\ne j\ne k}{} a_{ijk} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd do like in the second example. In the first, some trickery is used in order not to have the common subscript too deep.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathop{
  \vphantom{\sum^{N}}% to have the correct height
  \smash[b]{\sum_{j=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N}}% pretend there are no subscripts
}_{% now the global subscript
   \substack{
     \vphantom{j=1 k=1}% to take care of the smashed subscripts
     \\
     i\ne j\ne k
   }
}
\]

\[
\sum_{\substack{1\le j\le N \\ 1\le k\le N \\ i\ne j\ne k}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you make a macro out of the first example? You probably should if there's more than one occurrence of the construction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\doublesum}{e{_^}e{_^}e{_}}{%
  \mathop{%
    \vphantom{\sum^{#2#4}}%
    \smash[b]{%
      \sum_{#1\vphantom{#3}}^{#2} \sum_{#3\vphantom{#1}}^{#4}%
    }%
  }_{\substack{\vphantom{#1#2} \\ #5}}%
}


\begin{document}

\[
\doublesum _{j=1}^{N} _{k=1}^{N} _{i\ne j\ne k}
\]

\end{document}
```

Doing like this will avoid possible slight misalignment between the subscripts, because we equalize them with phantoms.

[image]